# Sending no match output rows to nowhere

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to redirect Lookup No Match output to "nowhere"?
Our business requirements do not require no match output for these cases, and I receive warnings when I don't redirect them to a transformation.

Note: Ignoring the no match will not do since NULLs are returned and the table does not accept nulls.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you tell if you are using 2005 or 2208? Lookup transformation works differently on these 2 versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the Derived Column transformation renamed to "bit bucket" to be an excellent destination for scenarios like this.

Others in the community are fans of the [Trash Destination](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/) (scroll to the bottom) for the same purpose.